# Is this possible? Array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a question, can i do this? Store variables in a same array.

```
int var1 = 20;
int var2 = 200;
int var20 = 100;

int array[3] = { var1, var2, var20 };

return 0;
```

Comment: You have an *answer*? What?

Comment: A question, I guess? Try it.

Comment: You may want to learn more about pointers. Take several days to read some good C programming book.

Comment: It's  possible later in C99.

Comment: There are two Answers and the OP still get downvoted. Why should one bother to Answer if the Question is not proper?

Comment: @Michi - To help, maybe....

Comment: @4386427 You are Funny :)))

Comment: @4386427 please see my Comment to Richard's Answer

Comment: @Michi - agree... that was exactly why I put both in my answer

Answer (score 6):

It depends where you have the code.

If it is as global variables like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int var1 = 20;
int var2 = 200;
int var20 = 100;

int array[3] = { var1, var2, var20 };

int main(void) {

     return 0;
}
```

it is illegal because the initializer isn't constant.

If you put it in a function like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int var1 = 20;
    int var2 = 200;
    int var20 = 100;

    int array[3] = { var1, var2, var20 };

    return 0;
}
```

it is valid code.

If you want you can also build the array from arguments passed to a function. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void someFunc(int var1, int var2, int var3)
{
    int array[3] = { var1, var2, var3 };
    for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int var1 = 20;
    int var2 = 200;
    int var20 = 100;

    someFunc(var1, var2, var20);

    return 0;   return 0;
}
```